# Какую модель лучше полиномиальной множественной регрессии использовать?

Tags: база-данных, статистика

Из все материала что я просмотрел я нашел два типа

1. **Y=B0+B1X1+B2X1^2+B3X2+B4X2^2**
2. **Y=B0+B1X1+B2X2+B12X1X2+B11X1^2+B22X2^2**
   Вопрос какую лучше использовать для полиномиального множественного анализа? Если второю, то как строится модель, в которой больше двух параметров?

Answer (score 0):

Какая модель лучше можно ответить только построив обе и сравнив результаты - например, используя RMSE. Универсального ответа нет и быть не может. Прием ответ для каждого конкретного набора данных может и будет разным.

Про "вторую модель" в которой "больше двух параметров" -  вопрос загадочен. Так как во-первых, в вашей "второй модели" ровно две независимых переменных, а во вторых -  в "первой вашей модели" их тоже две.  И параметров тоже "больше двух" в обоих моделях.